# How inspect Django models attributes and fields

Tags: django, django-models

Currently i am faced with a need to extend django's built-in auth user model extend and customize it for my needs. While i am reading django official documentation in explanation code use models which so purely documented or if code is documented it's dispersed throughout several links on the same django documentation.

I thought that certainly developers which faced with the same problem before me wrote modules which can inspect `django-modules` and other `django-source-code` i found some of mentioned modules tools like `django-inspect` or also `django-inspect-models` but as i see their profile pages on PyPi my conclusions was that they have problems with supporting recent django versions etc. Can anyone suggest me the appropriate module ?

Also before i got this thoughts i tried to find on django github source code models which i needed. But it wasnt easy because django source code structure difficult for me to understand. Can anyone suggest me appropriate and easy method to find models in django source code for example for this model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Where is i imported User model in django source code located ? 
Because in django source code hasn't 
`Django` folder where also hasn't `contrib` folder `auth` and `models` too

Comment: @IainShelvington a little bit

Comment: Well, generally when you import something in Python the "dotted" import path directly maps the to actual path that you are importing from. So `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` would look in 2 places for the class `User` - `django/contrib/auth/models/__init__.py` or `django/contrib/auth/models.py`. In this case it's here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L383

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you but i understand how import work in python. Really thank you but if you look to django source you wouldn't find  path which you assumed. Take look at it for fun

Comment: If you wish to see where the module is being served from locally, you can import the module (not a member of the module) and inspect it's `__file__` attribute. `from django.contrib.auth import models; print(models.__file__)`

Comment: I've looked through the Django source code a lot and I've never had an issue finding what I need

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you i will tried this method and its very helpfull

Comment: @IainShelvington i tried it today and it's so helpful and explicit way. Thank you! If you will write your message like answer i will mark it as appropriate